# Как в несмежную ячейку поместить критерий выбора из фильтра? Н\п фильтруем по цифре"2", и "2" должно отобразиться

Tags: excel, фильтр

Есть стандартная Excelевская таблица, небольшая. 10-15 строк, 1 столбец. Строки содержат цифры иногда разные, иногда одинаковые, иногда строки пустые. Нужно сформировать таблицу с одинаковыми цифрами. Это просто - стандартный Excelевский фильтр отлично подходит. Но. Одновременно АВТОМАТИЧЕСКИ должна заполниться несмежная ячейка, в которой должна отобразиться цифра-критерий. Например, фильтруем таблицу по цифре "2", должны отобразиться строки напротив цифры "2" и сама цифра "2" появиться в нужной ячейке. Фильтруем по "7" - значит, отображаются строки напротив "7" плюс "7" появляется в нужной ячейке и т.д.
Простите за глупый вопрос, я ботаник.

Comment: А если критерий фильтрации не конкретное число, например: >5; 2, 3 и  8; непустые?

Comment: К сожалению, конкретное. Это бухгалтерия, точнее, сертификация. Сертифицируется одна из нескольких ширин на партию. Ширины автоматом появляются в диапазоне, из которого фильтром выбирается одна. Именно она и должна отобразиться в определённых ячейках. Кроме этого, разумеется, остаются лишь строки с испытаниями именно этой ширины, но с этим отлично справляется стандартный фильтр.

Answer (score 0):

Если критерий фильтра - определенное число (т.е. в отфильтрованных строках таблицы остаются только строки с определенным числовым значением в нужном столбце), то для отображения критерия в отдельной ячейке можно применить штатную функцию листа - *ПРОМЕЖУТОЧНЫЕ.ИТОГИ*. Функция производит вычисления  (сумма, счет, произведение, стандартное отклонение, среднее значение, макс, мин) со значениями только видимых строк.

```
=ПРОМЕЖУТОЧНЫЕ.ИТОГИ(4;диапазон)
```

где *диапазон* - диапазон столбца, по которому происходит фильтрация;

*4* - номер функции (4 - определение максимального значения, 5 - наименьшего значения). Т.к. в видимых (отфильтрованных) строках остается только одно число (критерий фильтрации), то нет разницы, какое из значений искать - большее или меньшее.

Comment: vikttur, Вы - гений!!! Огромное спасибо!!! Неделю бился, не мог решить.

Comment: Слава Украине! Жыве Беларусь!